# Newbie: What is the easiest way to bulk add data to a sqlite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm a total newbie to SQL, and I'd like to know whether anyone knows a means for easily "copy and pasting" hundreds of entries to a sqlite database. Again, I'm not a professional programmer, so software that could automate that process would be great. (I primarily code in JavaScript, but SQL code can be used as well if you could kindly explain the code.)

Essentially, the text I'd be adding would be delimited by a character (the '|' character in my case) for the columns, and line breaks for the rows. It would be added onto a table that's already being used in the database, with columns already set up.

Thanks a lot!! Any suggestions are most appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/) and then File > Import > From CSV file.. after creating a New Database.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is working out so far, but how can I move the records from this new table onto a previously made table?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that out. I used "INSERT INTO abc SELECT * FROM xyz" in another SQLite program and it worked. Thank you!